# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'EmployeeService' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular-services

i am not able to call service into app component
app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './services/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public title: string = 'Services Demo';
  public employeeObj: any
  public empId: string;

  constructor( private employeeService: EmployeeService){

  }

  public getEmployeeDetail(): void{
   this.employeeObj = this.employeeService.getEmployee( this.empId );
  }

}
```

employee.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class EmployeeService{

    public employeeRecord = [
        {name: 'sowmya', city: 'Hyd', age:'23', id:'e1'},
        {name: 'so ni', city: 'Banglore', age:'22', id:'e2'},
        {name: 'sujith', city: 'Chennai', age:'43', id:'e3'},
        {name: 'suruchi', city: 'Delhi', age:'41', id:'e4'}
    ];

    public getEmployee ( id:string ): any{
        let employee: any;

        for ( let i=0; i < this.employeeRecord.length; i++){
            if( id === this.employeeRecord[i].id ){
                employee = this.employeeRecord[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `EmployeeService` from imports array of AppModule

Comment: Can you add the AppModule code here?

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
 

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeService } from './services/employee.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [EmployeeService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: [edit] your question with the code.. not add as comment